# Bathroom switch controls both fan and light

Tags: wiring, bathroom, switch, light, fans

Im trying to understand the way my bathroom switch is wired. I am wanting to wire my light and fan to separate switches. Previously there was a timer switch installed that would turn on both the light and the fan from one switch. I was expecting there to be a separate line for the light, and one for the fan that were both tied to the same switch and bought a 2 gang switch accordingly. Once I removed the previous switch though, I found the standard 2 black, 2 white setup. My assumption is that the light and fan are wired together somewhere further up the line (i.e inside the wall somewhere). Am i just SOL?

Comment: what is SOL ?..

Comment: @Ruskes S*** Out of Luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the light and fan are in one box then the wires are connected where they enter the box. If they are separate then they are linked together just like two light fixtures controlled by long switch.

The only real solution is to run another cable to one of the devices and disconnect the connection between them. Depending on how your house is built and on whether or not you have easy access to the ceiling (attic above) this could be anywhere from a small to a huge task. Sometimes the easiest wiring solution involves making holes in the wall and patching when done.

Answer (score 0):

So you have power going to the ceiling box that powers the fan and light together.

You could follow the instructions of

> The only real solution is to run another cable to one of the devices and disconnect the connection between them. Depending on how your house is built and on whether or not you have easy access to the ceiling (attic above) this could be anywhere from a small to a huge task. Sometimes the easiest wiring solution involves making holes in the wall and patching when done.

### OR

You can install one of the Fan/Light remote device in the ceiling box. It needs your 2 wires to get the power.
It has 2 wires in (power) and 3 wires output for light/Fan hots and one neutral.

The individual switching is done on the wall mounted remote switch without extra wires.

### You do not need to change your cables for this or open the wall to run new conduits.

It looks like something like this **This is an example only, they come in smaller size and UL listed so do your shopping.**

[image: remote]

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089CZYH87)

It is small enough that it might fit in the ceeling box

Comment: the device you showed is commonly for a ceiling fan. The OP was speaking of their bathroom fan.  Is that device suitable for a bath fan as well?  I know electrically it can be wired, but placement inside the wiring box could be an issue.   Maybe if all wires were in a larger box in the ceiling?   My mind is intrigued now.

Comment: You might want to source your quote...

Comment: @FreeMan The quote is from my answer. No need to source it. Not sure why not just "You could follow the instructions of the other answer to run a new cable, or" and leave out the quote, but I suppose that is a stylistic issue.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I realized that when I read your answer which was (at the time) listed below this one. It's generally considered polite to indicate that you're borrowing someone else's answer.

Comment: Conceptually this is OK, except for the concern as noted by RMDman that this is really designed for a ceiling fan and not an exhaust fan. That being said, this particular product, and many similar ones available on Amazon, gives no indication of proper UL/ETL/etc. certification, which is a **serious concern** with a hard-wired 120V (they say 110V - yet another clue this ain't right) device. It will *probably* work great and give years of reliable service. But if something goes wrong, the installer (homeowner - no electrician in their right mind will install this unlisted device) may end up

Comment: with a damaged house *and no insurance payment*. Not something I would recommend.

Comment: @FreeMan True, but "follow the instructions of" when it is plain text and not an installation manual image, with source text on the same page, is good enough for me, since it was my answer being quoted :-)